# How to get row click event in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I am trying get row object selected with row click event. I am using **Angular UI Grid**

Here is the API link
http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/103_filtering

I used this to get the data:

```
    enableRowSelection: true,
        multiSelect:false,
        onRegisterApi : function(gridApi){
  //set gridApi on scope
  $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
  gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope,function(row){
    var msg = 'row selected ' + row.isSelected;
    $log.log(msg);
  });
```

Here is my code
https://plnkr.co/edit/DqBgHFnwLpYM5pvg0f56?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject `ui.grid.selection` into your app module:

```
angular.module('app',['ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.selection'])
```

Setup selection on html:

```
<div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-selection class="grid" ></div>
```

Get selected row object using `row.entity`:

```
 gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope,function(row){
    var msg = 'row selected ' + row.entity.age;
    console.log(msg);
  });
```

Working plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/fxtD3F4iFxmPKT1G1t7V

Comment: is there any another way to do same thing ?? because it is showing check box ..I don't need check box .I just want to  click any where on row

Comment: @user944513: you can add `enableRowHeaderSelection: false` to turn off the checkbox

Comment: could you please look on this Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34612856/how-to-edit-column-in-value-in-angular-js

Comment: @user944513: sorry I don't have experience on inline editing