# how to edit column in value in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-grid

I am using UI-grid in my example .I saw the documentation from here of edit row .
http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/205_row_editable
In given example user able to edit the columns present in row.I also make same example also include modules but not able to edit my columns ..what is procedure to edit the columns ?

here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/zypDrZeJUx9ZoTHNnMxc?p=preview

already added the modules

```
angular.module('app',['ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.selection' ,'ui.grid.edit', 'ui.grid.rowEdit', 'ui.grid.cellNav'])
```

here is my JS file

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
        //filter demo
        // enableFiltering: true,
        // showHeader: false, // show header check
            enableRowSelection: true,
            multiSelect:false,
            //show checkbox front of each row or not
            enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
            onRegisterApi : function(gridApi){
      //set gridApi on scope
      $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
      gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope,function(row){
        var msg = 'row selected ' + row.entity.age;
        console.log(row);
      });
            },

             enableFiltering: true,


     columnDefs: [
         {
                 field: 'gender', 
                 displayName:'Gender',
                 filter: { 
                     type: uiGridConstants.filter.SELECT,
                     selectOptions: [ 
                         { value: 'm', label: 'male' },
                         { value: 'F', label: 'female' },
                         { value: 'N', label: 'mdd' }

                     ]
                 },
             },



       {field: 'name', displayName:'First'},
       {field: 'lastname', displayName:'Second',enableSorting: false}
       ]
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the demo, I hope this is what you wanted.

It's not exactly the same as yours anymore but you can still edit the code.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.edit', 'ui.grid.rowEdit', 'ui.grid.selection']);


app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$q', '$interval', 'uiGridConstants',
  function($scope, $http, $q, $interval, uiGridConstants) {
    $scope.data = [{
      name: 'abc',
      lastname: 'hrt',
      gender: 'm',
      age: 28

    }, {
      name: 'pqr',
      lastname: 'oiu',
      gender: 'F',
      age: 8

    }, {
      name: 'lqm',
      lastname: 'ytu',
      gender: 'N',
      age: 11

    }];

    $scope.gridOptions = {
      enableFiltering: true,
      enableRowSelection: true,
      multiSelect: false,
      enableRowHeaderSelection: false
    };

    $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [{
      name: 'gender',
      displayName: 'Gender',
      filter: {
        type: uiGridConstants.filter.SELECT,
        selectOptions: [{
            value: 'm',
            label: 'male'
          }, {
            value: 'F',
            label: 'female'
          }, {
            value: 'N',
            label: 'mdd'
          }

        ]
      }
    }, {
      name: 'name',
      displayName: 'First'
    }, {
      name: 'lastname',
      displayName: 'Second'
    }];

    $scope.saveRow = function(rowEntity) {
      // create a fake promise - normally you'd use the promise returned by $http or $resource
      var promise = $q.defer();
      $scope.gridApi.rowEdit.setSavePromise(rowEntity, promise.promise);

      promise.resolve();
    };

    $scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi) {
      //set gridApi on scope
      $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
      gridApi.rowEdit.on.saveRow($scope, $scope.saveRow);

      gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope, function(row) {
        var msg = 'row selected ' + row.entity.age;
        console.log(row);
      });
    };

    $scope.gridOptions.data = $scope.data;
  }
]);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-touch.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/csv.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/pdfmake.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-edit ui-grid-row-edit ui-grid-selection class="grid"></div>
  </div>


  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

For any further questions you're always welcome.
Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VZrOgoMpBG5pAd6wHAFE?p=preview).

Comment: there is code of row click in my code ..can we add that code ? mean can we add row click event..or we can't add click event while using editing

Comment: I am on chat..please type message

Comment: I am not able to write the text in that chat room may be less reputation

Comment: where i am here please check on fiddle as well as on previous chat..please check message